# How can I specify in Altium to leave out the dielectric layer for a portion of the board?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, heatsink, pcb-layers

I am trying to replace the dielectic layer in just a portion of the board and instead have that just be more copper. The idea is to essentially allow the PCB to use anything it lays flat on to be a heatsink. Kind of like a metal core PCB or a large rectangular via that is filled.

I'm banging my head on my PCB software (Altium) stack up and can't figure it out.

Comment: There's multiple things in a PCB stackup that are dielectric (core, prepreg, and solder mask); it's not clear what you're refering to. Do you mean solder mask?

Comment: Don't worry yet about how to represent it in Altium. Are you sure your PCB fab can manufacture this? Would a  [metal core pcb](https://www.protoexpress.com/blog/advantages-metal-core-printed-circuit-boards/) work just as well? Or could you just make a cut-out in your PCB and mount it on a copper pedestal as a separate step?

Comment: I've never heard of a PCB fab that can manufacture something like this, and it's definitely not standard; you should ask your fab first *if* they can do it, and second how you should represent it in the gerber files you send them.

Comment: Ok so I was not exactly aware of how pcbs are fabricated and now understand that what I was asking is not typical and would be very weird to try and fabricate. I have elected to instead use polygon pours on both sides and a ton of vias to get the same "anything the pcb sits flat on is the heatsink" effect i was trying to describe earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the board up as a Rigid Flex PCB. That will allow to to define multiple stackups in the PCB. You just won't have any flex regions.

To do this go into the layer stack manager and go to Features -> Rigid-Flex.

Then you can go into board planning mode and use split lines to create board regions for each part of the PCB and choose its stackup.

I also encourage you to make sure your PCB stackup is manufacturable with a PCB Fab house. Its a little unclear what you need and seems very non standard.

Comment: Ok so I was not exactly aware of how pcbs are fabricated and now understand that what I was asking is not typical and would be very weird to try and fabricate. I have elected to instead use polygon pours on both sides and a ton of vias to get the same "anything the pcb sits flat on is the heatsink" effect i was trying to describe earlier.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and i'll try messing around with that feature